# opencv 3.4 imshow() opens a second window with the same name as already opened with namedWindow

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2017, imshow

Due to other libaries I like to use, I ported my project from Linux Mint 17.2 with Eclipse and OpenCv 3.2.0 to Windows 10 Visual Studio 2017 and OpenCv 3.4.1.
I solved the typical OS issues and was able to compile the code.

What I observe now should not be possible! The following code opens two windows with the same name:

```
    const string RefFrame = "Referenz Frame\0";
    const string MatchFrame = "Matching Frame\0";
    const string FinalFrame = "Transformated Frame\0";
    namedWindow(RefFrame, WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow(RefFrame, 600,600);
    namedWindow(MatchFrame, WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow(MatchFrame, 600,600);
    namedWindow(FinalFrame, WINDOW_NORMAL);
    resizeWindow(FinalFrame, 600,600);


    bool ready = false;
    vector<Point2f> ListOfPointsInReferenzFrame,   
    ListOfPointsInMatchingFrame;

    while (!ready) {
        ReferenzFrameWithFeature = ReferenzFrame.clone();
        MatchingFrameWithFeature = MatchingFrame.clone();
        this->DrawMatches(RefFrame, ReferenzFrameWithFeature,     ListOfPointsInReferenzFrame);
        this->DrawMatches(MatchFrame, MatchingFrameWithFeature, ListOfPointsInMatchingFrame);
```

Where "DrawMatches()" looks like:

```
    void tManualImageMatching::DrawMatches(const std::string WindowName,         cv::Mat &Image, std::vector<cv::Point2f> &ListOfPoints)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < ListOfPoints.size(); i++) {
            circle(Image,cvPoint((int) ListOfPoints[i].x,         (int)ListOfPoints[i].y),20,Scalar(0,0,0),2);//draw circle in point 100,100
        }
        imshow(WindowName, Image);
        resizeWindow(WindowName, 600,600);
    }
```

In my Linux code with opencv 3.2.0 (build with eclipse) this works fine. Under Windows the properties are lost for the second window with the same name. -> The new window is opened with type "WINDOW_AUTOSIZE", which means that the resizeWindow command does not work here.

What can I do to reduce to one window with each name?